# A question about the Kähler cone of $\mathbb{C}P^n\sharp\mathbb{C}P^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I have found in Mathoverflow [Kähler cone of $\mathbb{C}P^n\sharp\mathbb{C}P^n$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96118/what-does-the-k%C3%A4hler-cone-of-the-one-point-blow-up-of-mathbbcpn-look-like)  that :

Let $X=\mathbb{C}P^n\sharp\mathbb{C}P^n$ be the blowing up at a point.  The Kähler cone of $X$ is 
$$\mathcal{P}\backsimeq \{ a,b\in \mathbb{R}^2| a>0,b>0,a>b\}$$
There the author presents the proof of the above isomorphism, however I cannot understand. Can anyone offer more explicit proof or some references of this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Dima  I just have searched this book and find the proof. Thank you for your comment

Comment: The blowup of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ at a point is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{CP}^n\#\overline{\mathbb{CP}^n}$, not $\mathbb{CP}^n\#\mathbb{CP}^n$. For $n$ even, the two spaces are not even homotopy equivalent.